# Magento 1.9 TinyMCE not allow <a href=”#”><div class=”image”><img src=”my.jpg” /></div></a>

Tags: magento-1.9, tinymce

My magento version is  1.9 and I want to change some styles+html at  one page. So when I try to use TinyMCE for this it not allow me to put like below.

hyperlink or an anchor -div tag-image tag-close div tag- close hyperlink or an anchor

But it allow me to put anchor tags only  for img tags. I found the article how we can change the setting to allow this but  the setup  js file at the magento 1.9 dont have  those settings. So any one have solution for this?

below is the article I found. unfortunately I cant find those settings in my js file.

http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/overcoming-magentos-wysiwyg-part-2-customizing-tinymce-settings/

Comment: please explain question i not understand....

Answer (score 2):

Alan Storm has covered these issues in his [article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_html5_tinymce). Apologies for linking to an off-site article but there is quite a lot there, too much to paste here.

I have ran into your issue before and I fixed it with Alan's approach coupled with Silas Palmer's comment (on the article) additions.